# Elegant way to validate scala map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

My program receives a scala map, the requirements is to validate this map (key-value pairs). Ex: validate a key value, change its value to an acceptable format etc. In a rare case, we update the key as well before passing the map to the down layer. Its not always required to update this map , but only when we detect that there are any unsupported keys or values. However, we have to check all key/value pairs. I'm doing some thing like this:

```
private def updateMap ( parameters: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {

parameters.map{

  case(k,v) => k match { case "checkPool" =>


    (k, (if (k.contains("checkPool"))
      v match {
        case "1" => "true"
        case _ => "false"
      }
    else v))

  case "Newheader" => (k.replace("Newheader","header"),v)
  case _ =>(k,v)
  }


  case _ => ("","")
}

}
```

Like this the code increases for doing the validation and converting the keys/values to supported ones. Is there a cleaner way of doing this validation in Scala for a map?

Thanks

Comment: Are key values to equal "NewHeader" and "checkPool" or are they part of a longer string (you use the contains function)? If they are part of the key strings then Ramesh Maharjan's solotion is good otherwise there exists a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

It will be clearer if you put all your patterns above one another:

```
parameters.map{
  case (k@"checkPool", "1") => k -> "true"
  case (k@"checkPool", _") => k -> "false"
  case ("Newheader", v) => "header" -> v
  // put here all your other cases
  case (k, v) => k -> v  //last possible case, if nothing other matches
}
```

For clarity, you can also put different validators in partial functions:

```
type Validator = PartialFunction[(String, String), (String, String)
val checkPool: Validator = {
  case (k@"checkPool", "1") => k -> "true"
  case (k@"checkPool", _") => k -> "false"
}
val headers: Validator = {
  case ("Newheader", v) => "header" -> v
}
```

And then put all your validators one after the other in your `map`:

```
parameters.map(
  checkPool orElse
   headers orElse
   ... orElse
   PartialFunction(identity[(String, String)]) //this is the same as case (k, v) => k -> v
)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple `if else` condition matching seems to be the best choice.

```
def updateMap(parameters: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
  parameters.map(kv => {
    var key = kv._1
    var value = kv._2
    if(key.contains("checkPool")){
      value = if(value.equals("1")) "true" else "false"
    }
    else if(key.contains("Newheader")){
      key = key.replace("Newheader", "header")
    }
    (key, value)
  })
}
```

You can add more `else` `if` conditions